# PHP how to get the content of an array inside a function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to educate myself more on arrays and foreach statements.

In one file I have the following class and function:

```
class Onboarding_Dashboard {

static function dashboard_onboarding_content() {
    $items = array(
        'stage-1' => array(
            'title' => 'Hello',
            'content' => 'This is some content text',
            'show-next' => 'true',
            'show-prev' => 'true',
        ),
        'stage-2' => array(
            'title' => 'Hello',
            'content' => 'This is some content text',
            'show-next' => 'true',
            'show-prev' => 'true',
        )


    )
}    
}
```

In another file I'd like to use the content of this to create a foreach statement. Something like this:

```
static function action_get_content() {
    $items = Onboarding_Dashboard::dashboard_onboarding_content();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo '<h2>'.$item['title'].'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.$item['content'].'</p>';
    }

}
```

But I'm not sure what else I need to add in order to get the data from my Class function dashboard_onboarding_content

UPDATE: I've updated my foreach statement, and wrapped it in a function. How do I cho the reults of this function at another point in my code - is it as simple as doing

```
echo action_get_content();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to answer the OP's comment*

As the op asked how to make another function which handles the foreach which he can then echo, i have added the `dashboard_foreach_example()` function.

```
class Onboarding_Dashboard {

    static function dashboard_onboarding_content(){
        $items = array(
            'stage-1' => array(
                'title' => 'Hello',
                'content' => 'This is some content text',
                'show-next' => 'true',
                'show-prev' => 'true',
            ),
            'stage-2' => array(
                'title' => 'Hello',
                'content' => 'This is some content text',
                'show-next' => 'true',
                'show-prev' => 'true',
            )
        );

        return $items;
    }    

    static function dashboard_foreach_example(){
        $items = self::dashboard_onboarding_content();
        $output = '';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $output .= '<h2>'.TITLE ATTRIBUTE.'</h2>';
            $output .= '<p>'.TITLE ATTRIBUTE.'</p>';
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

You can now simply echo the `dashboard_foreach_example()` as it will generated the output in the function

```
echo Onboarding_Dashboard::dashboard_foreach_example();
```

Comment: This is close to where I was getting to actually. Quick question, say I want to wrap my foreach statement in a function (action_get_content) how do I echo it out elsewhere - I'll update my question so you can see what I mean

Comment: Awesome, that works - do I have to keep dashboard_foreach_example in the same file as the above function?

Comment: As it is right now it's a function in the same class, therefore cant really be split up, but you can make a new function which does the same as long as you change the `$items` to actually reach the `dashboard_onboarding_content()` function

Comment: So if I change $items to be $items = Onboarding_Dashboard::dashboard_onboarding_content(); then it should work in another class right?

Comment: Exactly :) you got it

Comment: Oh one more quick question - How can I echo out the item number in the array? so Just a 1 for the first item, 2 for the second item etc?

Comment: If you want to actually say `1` , `2` you'll have to create a variable before the foreach and increment inside the foreach, but if you want to get `stage-1`,`stage-2` etc, you can change the foreach to `foreach ($items as $key => $item)`, `$key` will then hold `stage-1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to return the array:

```
class Onboarding_Dashboard {
   static function dashboard_onboarding_content() {
      // your $items array stays here
      return $items;
   }
}

function action_get_content() {
   $html = '';
   foreach (Onboarding_Dashboard::dashboard_onboarding_content() as $item) {
      $html .= '<h2>'.$item['title'].'</h2>';
      $html .= '<p>'.$item['title'].'</p>';
   }
   return $html;
}
```

Then you output it this way:

```
echo action_get_content();
```

Alternatively you can have this function as part of your class:

```
class Onboarding_Dashboard {
   static function dashboard_onboarding_content() {
      // your $items array stays here
      return $items;
   }

   static function action_get_content() {
      $html = '';
      foreach (self::dashboard_onboarding_content() as $item) {
         $html .= '<h2>'.$item['title'].'</h2>';
         $html .= '<p>'.$item['title'].'</p>';
      }
      return $html;
   }
}
```

Then you output it this way:

```
echo Onboarding_Dashboard::action_get_content();
```